# Auto kill child process when parent process is died

Tags: linux, go

How to **auto kill child process** when parent process is **died** in **Golang** ?

The child process is invoked by **exec.Command()**.

For example,

The parent process pid is: 28290, there is three child process: 32062, 32473, 33455.

# ps axo pid, ppid, pgid | grep 28290

PID      PPID  PGID

28290     1   28289

32062 28290 28289

32473 28290 28289

33455 28290 28289

The four process have the same PGID=28289.

When I kill the parent process 28290(**kill the 28290 in linux, kill -9 28290**), the child processes does not exit().

Is there any options to auto kill the child processes?

Answer (score 2):

Set process group ID before running the command, and kill by -pid, pay attention to the minus sign.

```
// set pgid so all child processes can be killed together
cmd.SysProcAttr = &syscall.SysProcAttr{Setpgid: true}
...
// kill -pgid (-pid)
syscall.Kill(-cmd.Process.Pid, syscall.SIGKILL)
```

Comment: When I set the Setpid:true, the fource processes get different PGID. When I kill the parent process, the child process also survive.

Comment: Pay attention to the minus sign "-cmd.Process.Pid"